# PDO bindvalue does not work (WHERE LIKE statement)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to use a LIKE statement to search through a number of columns.

The following code gives the wanted result:

```
$zoek='%'.$_GET['zoek'].'%';
$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );

//insert the user:
$sql = "SELECT `leerlingnr`,`voornaam`,`achternm_tsnvoegsels`,`klas`
FROM `roosters` 
WHERE `leerlingnr` LIKE '$zoek'
OR `voornaam` LIKE '$zoek'
OR `achternm_tsnvoegsels` LIKE '$zoek'
OR `klas` LIKE '$zoek'";
$st = $conn->prepare ( $sql );
$st->execute();
var_dump ( $st -> fetchAll ( ) ) ;
$conn = null;//sluit de connectie
```

However, when I try to bind the `$zoek` value, instead of just inserting it in the query, I get 0 results.

```
$zoek='%'.$_GET['zoek'].'%';
$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );

//insert the user:
$sql = "SELECT `leerlingnr`,`voornaam`,`achternm_tsnvoegsels`,`klas`
FROM `roosters` 
WHERE `leerlingnr` LIKE ':zoekterm1'
OR `voornaam` LIKE ':zoekterm2'
OR `achternm_tsnvoegsels` LIKE ':zoekterm3'
OR `klas` LIKE ':zoekterm4'";
$st = $conn->prepare ( $sql );
$st->bindValue( ':zoekterm1', $zoek, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st->bindValue( ':zoekterm2', $zoek, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st->bindValue( ':zoekterm3', $zoek, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st->bindValue( ':zoekterm4', $zoek, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st->execute();
var_dump ( $st -> fetchAll ( ) ) ;
$conn = null;//sluit de connectie
```

After trying for about half an hour (I fixed having % in the query and having only one `:zoekterm`), I really don't see what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When binding variables, don't use quotes.

Comment: Ah, well, that fixed it.
Thanks!